# golang grpc socket tuning

Tags: sockets, go, grpc

I have a golang client application talking a server via GRPC. I noticed that while the application is running that the number of sockets accumulated on the client app keeps climbing till around 9000. At which point I pause client. However, after there are no more traffic between the client and the server the number sockets still stayed at that level even after 8 hours.

Is there anyway we can tune GRPC for socket usage? Such as closing sockets after a timeout? Is using streaming another way to limit number of sockets being opened?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe you do not close connection when you are done ?

Comment: There's a Close() call on ClientConn type. But I think this will close all the sockets instead of the idle sockets.

Comment: Have you tried to put a timeout on your context? Take a look at keepalive package github.com/grpc/grpc-go/keepalive MaxConnectionIdle

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by making sure that your client application cleans up unused connections (grpc.ClientConn) by calling Close() method on it.
Also, since I don't know what exactly your application does so I'm gonna go ahead and suggest reusing connections for multiple RPCs (you're probably already doing this).

And to answer your question about setting timeout deadline on connections:
1. You shouldn't have to do this. Feel free to open up an issue on https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go about whatever gRPC shortcoming is forcing you to take this route.
2.  But if you must know, you can use a custom dialer(https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/13975c070286c7371aa3a8b3c230e90d7bf029fc/clientconn.go#L333) and set a deadline on the net.Conn that you return from it.

Best,
Mak